# In Finder's List view, is there a keyboard shortcut to go to top/bottom of list?

Tags: keyboard, finder

Before Leopard, hitting the Spacebar would take you to the bottom file in List view -- but that now initiates QuickLook. As far as I know there has never been a keyboard shortcut to go to the top of the list. Or am I just ignorant?

Answer (score 36):

Yep!  You can use <kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>↑</kbd> to jump to the top of the list and <kbd>opt</kbd>-<kbd>↓</kbd> to jump to the bottom.

Comment: O frabjous day!!  Glory be!!  This has absolutely made my day, Dave! Many thanks indeed! -- Drew

Comment: it's like being lifted out of the dark ages

Comment: This doesn't appear to be working on El Capitan.

Comment: I don’t know about El Cap, but it still works under Sierra.

Comment: Can I just poll the community here on whether this is intuitive? Personally, I've always found it profoundly confusing that Command+<direction> is "scroll to end" in every other context (text editor, browser, etc.), but that those have specific actions in Finder.

Answer (score 3):

Control-Option-Up and Control-Option-Down appear to work in El Capitan.

Comment: Hi Ron, Welcome to Ask Different, please add a few details to your answer to maintain high quality of the form.

Comment: Looks fine to me, what's the problem?

Comment: Fun fact: this only works in list view, but not in icon view.

Comment: Does anyone know the corresponding shortcut for icon view?

Answer (score 3):

In macOS Big Sur (Version 11), when viewing items in list view in Finder, the keyboard shortcut  **⌃ + ⌥ + △** selects the first/top item in the list, and the keyboard shortcut **⌃ + ⌥ + ▽** selects the last/bottom item in the list. These keyboard shortcuts do not work in icon view.

---

In macOS Sonoma (Version 14) [and perhaps earlier versions of macOS, but I'm not sure], when viewing items in list or icon view in Finder, the keyboard shortcut   **+ ◁** scrolls the view to the top, and the keyboard shortcut  **+ ▷** scrolls the view to the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

In MacOS Monterey, the best shortcut is +⬅️ (fn+left arrow) to scroll to the top in list view or icon view in finder. fn+arrows can also page up or down, or scroll to the bottom in finder. These also work in other apps like Safari, Chrome and any apps with scrollable content.

This likely also works in Big Sur and earlier MacOS releases as well, like Mojave, High Sierra, Sierra, El Capitan, Yosemite, etc because I've known about this for a long time. Surprised not many others knew.